# Why am I getting an error like this, "undefined is not an object route.key"?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use the react-navigation library to create navigation between two components.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const Section = ({children, title}): Node => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
undefined is not an object route.key
```

I tried installing the necessary libraries through the react-navigation website and the version is 6x. Please let me know where am I doing the error. It has been like 2-3 days and I am finding no luck with this library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967903/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-route-key-react-navigation

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement other dependency library perfectly like below

npm install @react-navigation/native
npm install react-native-screens
npm install react-native-safe-area-context
npm install @react-navigation/native-stac

After that you can check the code below how it’s done.

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native- stack';
import {
   SafeAreaView,
   ScrollView,
   StatusBar,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   useColorScheme,
   View,
 } from 'react-native';
 const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
 function HomeScreen() {
   return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
     </View>
  );
}
const App: () => Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
    </>
   );
  };
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
   }, 
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
 });
 export default App;
```